# Generate different pages on the basis of different contents

Tags: html, jekyll

Let me assume that I have the following architecture

_components (folders)

1. x1.html
2. x2.html
3. x3.html

I have a first page where I got the information from the YAM section for every component.

[image]

At this point I would like to add a link for every component to another page where I will display the component in a bigger manner.

So, let me assume I have, in the first page :

```
<div class="col-md-1">
                <a href="componentbig.html"><span id= "logos" class="material-icons">&#xE85B;</span></a>
            </div>
```

and In the componentbig.html I would like to open the right component on the basis of the link.

Do you have any suggestions for me ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand You correctly, then [collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) might be the feature You are looking for. For example, I'm usually using collections to generate a list of products and then have a specific page for each product also. Also make sure You check the [easy tutorial by Ben Balter](http://ben.balter.com/2015/02/20/jekyll-collections/).

Comment: You should extract the most useful parts from these links into your. The links may not be available in the future, and makes your answer easier to find!

Comment: @Günter, I'm using the collection in other parts in the web-site but here is different. When you land on the secondo page you need to get information about where you are from. How to say to jekyll this information in the right way ? On the basis of the previous "click" it has to generate the right content in the second page!

Comment: Jekyll is a static site generator therefore You cannot create sites on the fly this way and it does not hold information about sessions. What You are trying to achieve is a dynamic solution. You could try to parse the referer HTTP header from request using JavaScript and then generate the new page also with JavaScript.